# IntelliJ IDEA inspector does not work anymore for github project?

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, ide

I have been using IntelliJ IDEA on many projects. But this is my first time to use it on a Github synced project. And I just found the inline inspector seems does not work anymore.

When I drag it into the IDEA, I got the message told me I need to add VCS root for the project so I added. And nothing showed even after I compiled it.

[image: No more inline inspection anymore :(]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot, `src` directory is not marked as Source.

[Mark the directory as the Source Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-content-roots.html).